# Find all real numbers $x$ satisfying $[x+2]=6[x] -23$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is a *homework puzzle* so I'm not asking for the direct answer.

> **Find all numbers $x$ in $\Bbb R$ for:**
>
> $$[x+2] = 6[x] - 23$$

I haven't see greatest integer functions that have a scalar out the front nor two GIF in one function. Could someone please help me understand how to solve this? :)

Comment: Sketch a graph? Or note that each side of the equation will always be an integer, so solve for $x$ an integer, and then consider the range of solutions around that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's long enough that I can add a full answer. By the first hint, you have that,

$$\begin{align}[x+2]\overset{1}{=}[x]+2&=6[x]-23\\5[x]&=25\\\ [x]&=5\\(2) \implies  5\le &x \lt6\end{align}$$

So, the solution is $$\boxed{5 \le x \lt6}$$

---

**Hint:**

1. $[x+I]=[x]+I$ for $I$ an integer.
2. $[x]=I \implies I\le x \lt I+1$ for $I$ an integer.

Comment: $-1$ We don't know if the homework deadline passed or not. Also, we can't be sure that the OP has already solved the problem using the hints in the previous version..

Comment: Are you going to down vote because of that?

Comment: And BTW, I am not sure if I can take an answer that elaborates nothing more than my hints an hour later getting three upvotes for no reason.

Comment: @JD I would now edit to remove that answer. Would you retract the down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote or upvote anyone on this thread. I just wrote "-1" in my comment. Obviously someone else downvoted your answer!

Comment: This is just crazy. So, I should never write an answer to this site? @JD

Comment: Of course you should continue to answer, and some people will continue to downvote! Hopefully they provide an elaboration when they do.